# Telling if Two dates are a Month Apart

Tags: java, calendar

I am having some slight issue with this program. I assume a month apart is 30 days in between the two dates. The program works for all the test dates except for the call monthApart(2, 14, 3, 15) which returns false instead of true. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

This program is supposed to tell if two dates are a month apart. It is assumed that the user inputs a valid month and day.  Write a method named monthApart that accepts four integer parameters representing two calendar dates. Each date consists of a month (1 through 12) and a day (1 through the number of days in that month [28-31]). The method returns whether the dates are at least a month apart. Assume that all dates in this problem occur during the same year. For example,

> Following dates are all considered to be at least a month apart from
>   9/19 (September 19): 2/14, 7/25, 8/2, 8/19, 10/19, 10/20, and 11/5.
>
> The following dates are NOT at least a month apart from 9/19: 9/20,
>   9/28, 10/1, 10/15, and 10/18.

Note that the first date could come before or after (or be the same as) the second date. Assume that all parameter values passed are valid.

Answers to the problem:
         Call:                          Answer: Result:

1   monthApart(6, 14, 9, 21)    true    true

2   monthApart(4, 5, 5, 15)     true    true

3   monthApart(4, 15, 5, 15)    true    true

4   monthApart(4, 16, 5, 15)    false   false

5   monthApart(6, 14, 6, 8)     false   false

6   monthApart(7, 7, 6, 8)      false   false

7   monthApart(7, 8, 6, 8)      true    true

8   monthApart(10, 14, 7, 15)   true    true

9   monthApart(2, 14, 3, 15)    true    false

10  monthApart(1, 1, 12, 31)    true    true

Sample calls:

> Call  Returns     Because monthApart( 6, 14, 9, 21)   true    June 14th is
>   at least a month before September 21st
>
> monthApart( 4, 5, 5, 15)  true    April 5th is at least a month before
>   May 15th
>
> monthApart( 4, 15, 5, 15)     true    April 15th is at least a month before
>   May 15th
>
> monthApart( 4, 16, 5, 15)     false   April 16th is NOT at least a month
>   before May 15th
>
> monthApart( 6, 14, 6, 8)  false   June 14th is NOT at least a month
>   apart from June 8th
>
> monthApart( 7, 7, 6, 8)   false   July 7th is NOT at least a month apart
>   from June 8th
>
> monthApart( 7, 8, 6, 8)   true    July 8th is at least a month after June
>   8th
>
> monthApart( 10, 14, 7, 15)    true    October 14th is at least a month
>   after July 15th

My code is messy right now; I'll clean it up later.

```
public static boolean monthApart(int monthOne, int dayOne, int monthTwo, int dayTwo){
    int monthDays = -1; 
    int monthMin = Math.min(monthOne, monthTwo); // Gets the lesser month

    if (monthOne<1 || monthOne >12 || monthTwo>12 || monthOne<1) { // If not a possible month
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of range");
    }

    switch(monthMin) { // Gets the corresponding last day of month
        case 1:
            monthDays = 31;
            break;
        case 2:
            monthDays = 28;
            break;
        case 3:
            monthDays = 31;
            break;
        case 4:
            monthDays = 30;
            break;
        case 5:
            monthDays = 31;
            break;
        case 6:
            monthDays = 30;
            break;
        case 7:
            monthDays = 31;
            break;
        case 8: 
            monthDays = 31;
            break;
        case 9:
            monthDays = 30;
            break;
        case 10:
            monthDays = 31;
            break;
        case 11:
            monthDays = 30;
            break;
        case 12:
            monthDays = 31;
            break;
    }

    int dayFirst = -1; // Plan: Last day of month-day of lower month + days on next month
    int daySecond = -1;
    if (monthOne<monthTwo) {
        dayFirst = dayOne;
        daySecond = dayTwo;
    } else if (monthOne>monthTwo) {
        dayFirst = dayTwo;
        daySecond = dayOne;
    }

    if (Math.abs(monthOne-monthTwo)>1) { // More than a month apart
        return true;
    } else if (monthOne==monthTwo) { // Same month
        return false;
    } else if (Math.abs(monthOne-monthTwo)==1) { // Adjacent months

        if (((monthDays-dayFirst) + daySecond) < 30 ) { // Gets difference in days
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use `Calendar` or `JodaTime`

Comment: Yep. I'm supposed to be able to finish this with what the book went over, so I don't want to use anything that is not covered with the book so far.

Comment: you don't need to use `monthDays` to determine whether or not the days in adjacent months are one month apart or not...there is a simpler way...

Comment: if(monthOne<1 || monthOne >12 || monthTwo>12 || monthOne<1) . Are you sure the last argument is monthOne? :). BTW why dont you use a debugger?

Comment: If you assume that "a month apart" is 30 days then your program is correct, because 2/14 and 3/15 are 29 days apart. What result did you expect?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure what the question means by "one month apart." Bases on the answers, it sometimes is 30 days and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that 1 month = 30 days when common knowledge (I know, I just started down a slippery slope) maintains that not all months are 30 days long -- in fact, most aren't. If I issue a net 30 bill for consulting, it's due in 30 days, not 28 days and not 31 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check `if (((monthDays-dayFirst) + daySecond) < 30 )` part of your code. 
In fact, you can simply see if this comparison is correct by substituting values.

Call to `monthApart(2, 14, 3, 15)` would make `monthDays` to be 28, `dayFirst` to 14, `daySecond` to 15.Thus making the comparison to 28 - 14 + 15 < 30  , which is true.

I'm assuming you made a mistake of not counting the start date in above calculation. (i.e. total number of days form Jan1 to Jan31 is 31-1+1 = 31 days, not 31-1=30 days.)

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Instead of assuming that a "month apart" is 30 days, it should be the number of days in that month.

```
    if (((monthDays-dayFirst) + daySecond) < 30 ) { // Gets difference in days
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Should be...

```
    if (((monthDays-dayFirst) + daySecond) < monthDays) { // Gets difference in days
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```